# Clarification on custom event param limits in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I've gone over a ton of documentation on this topic and still aren't sure if the 25 custom params/property limit in Firebase is per app or per event name?

Say I have 50 different events with 5 unique property names each, that would be a total of 250 unique property names. Is such a thing supported or do I start with a limit of 25 across all events?

I have Firebase hooked up to Bigquery so I'm less concerned about the limitations in the Firebase reporting admin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**Limitations for each Firebase project:**

Limit for 25 params is per [logEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#logEvent(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) call.

Limit for 500 events is per app instance.

Limit for 50 custom parameter (40 numeric and 10 texts) is the global limit in Google Analytics for Firebase dashboard.

No limit for custom parameters in Big Query.

This is as of 03/20/2018.

Comment: It should be noted that "Each parameter that you specify counts toward the project limit of 50. For example, if you specify the same parameter for 3 different events, then that counts as 3 of your 50." Taken from here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304

Answer (score 1):

The limits are [documented here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en).

> Google Analytics for Firebase lets you specify up to 25 custom
>   parameters per event (Android or iOS).
>
> You can also identify up to 50 of those custom event parameters per
>   [project](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en) (40 numeric and 10 textual) to include in reporting by registering
>   those parameters with their corresponding events. Once you register
>   your custom parameters, Google Analytics for Firebase displays a
>   corresponding card showing the data in each related event-detail
>   report.

The [javadoc for logEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#logEvent(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) gets more specific:

> The event can have up to 25 parameters. Events with the same name must
>   have the same parameters. Up to 500 event names are supported. Using
>   predefined FirebaseAnalytics.Event and/or FirebaseAnalytics.Param is
>   recommended for optimal reporting.

Comment: Thanks Doug, this is helpful. What do you think are the repercussions if we are sending events which have the same name but not necessarily the same parameters? This seems to be very inefficient and will require a lot of extra coding for nothing.